debug the pinescript strategy to work on renko charts
I wrote a pinescript strategy to test my trading strategy on renko charts. The problem occured was, as renko is a price based chart, at a certain time, there may be multiple renko bricks. For example, at 7.15  4 renko bricks formed and my condition for Long also met, in the backtesting, the pinescript will show that the long was executed on the first block of the 7.15, whereas, the actual market price at 7.15 will be at 4th block (as it appeared at the same time). One possible solution to this is, to check the time of the current brick, and its next brick. unfortunately, in pinedcript, we can see the details of its previous bricks only, not the future brick, Thus, getting the time of next brick is not possible. How do I solve this?
One possible solution to this is, to check the time of the current brick, and its next brick. unfortunately, in pinedcript, we can see the details of its previous bricks only, not the future brick, Thus, getting the time of next brick is not possible. How do I solve this?

about Backtesting on Non-Standard Charts

Renko prices are synthetic and no matter what, they differ. The maximum you can trust on Trading Renko on 1Second Chart is Two Days data, after that all is synthetic and not reliable. Also any calculation you are performing on Renko Chart does not happen until the future brick is closed. For examples, Try TimeNow function and see the result.
